# Importing Keras modules : Facing issues with an ML image classifier app - "Keeps on loading but no prediction output"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, tf.keras

I am building a Machine Learning application using CNN resnet50 architecture for image classification. This simple web app will take an image as input from the user and will predict the picture in the image followed by the developed model.

Issue statement:
The web-app keeps on loading when I click 'predict image' after attaching an input image.

Tools:
Python 3.9,
Tensorflow,
Resnet50 architecture

My code scenario:

1. I had imported the following modules from tensorflow: showing errors for all three!

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
```

2. Tried to fix the error using as follows: Are these right? (I simply used pip to install packages)

```
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
```

Additional Question:
3. The same ML model (in .h5 extension) provides different output (prediction) in a different machine. What may be the reason for it?

4. Why are the installed packages stored in default site-packages instead of the created project environment?

Thank you.

Comment: Before installing any package ensure you have activated the virtual environment of your project.This is the issue with beginners and experienced most of the time.

Comment: @MSS yes the virtual environment was already activated while initiating the project.